# Incomprehension about how tag scores are actually computed.

Tags: support, badges

While tracking the [abstract-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abstract-algebra) bronze badge, I noticed that some of the recent upvotes I got on answers to questions featuring this tag did not increase my [abstract-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abstract-algebra) score. Actually, they seemed to not have been taken into account at all.

Disappointed, I decided to investigate on the matter and I [summed up all the upvotes I got](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:285416+[abstract-algebra]) on answers to [abstract-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abstract-algebra) questions. I ended up finding $94$ ; I got $97$ total upvotes on the [abstract-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abstract-algebra) tag and $3$ of them are on questions I asked. However, on my [user profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/285416/c-falcon?tab=profile), the displayed score for this tag is $89$.

[image]

Therefore, how the tag scores are actually computed?

Any enlightenment will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Two possibilities: the scores are not updated in real-time; or, you have answered CW questions with that tag, which don't count towards your score.

Comment: The tag scores in the profile are updated only once a day. If that doesn't account for the difference, that would be due to CW answers usually.

Comment: It must be the first possibility then, I never answered community-wiki questions. I'll keep an eye on my score to see whether or not it'll increase in the coming few days. Thank you both for your reply!

Comment: Yep, it's in sync now. Displays 97, and a "manual" score count also gave 97.

Comment: @J.M. It is more relevant whether the *answer* is CW. (Of course, answer to a CW-question is automatically CW, but it is possible to post a CW answer to a non-CW question.)

Comment: @Martin, ah, I forgot about that possibility; thanks for the extra accuracy!

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you for your personal involvement!